# Same Question with answer already existent

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, answers

What if an answer to my question already exists but I'm looking for an alternative solution that suits my current level of knowledge better? Is it still redundant to post the same question again or is it fine?

Comment: If you post the question, be sure to include a link to the other question, and an explanation of exactly what it is that you want that isn't provided by the answer(s) to the other question.